# Rails js.erb file not being executed

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am simply trying to get my index.js.erb file to execute an alert("hi") command, however it is not working. I am pretty new to rails, and I was wondering if you guys could help me out! It looks like the servers_controller.rb index method is not executing format.js correctly. Any suggestions/ideas?

**servers_controller.rb**

```
def index
    @servers = Server.all

    update_all_servers #calls the method update_all_servers in application_controller.rb

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @servers }
      format.js #index.js.erb
    end
end
```

**index.js.erb**

```
alert("hi");
$("#comments").fadeOut();
```

**index.html**

```
<%- model_class = Server.new.class -%>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.pluralize %></h1>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
 <!--     <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:id) %></th> -->
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:hostname) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:port) %></th>
  <!--    <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:username) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:password) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:ssh_username) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:ssh_password) %></th> 
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:source_branch) %></th> -->
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:source_revision) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:release) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:rhel_version) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:gpu_type) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:total_users) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:current_users) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:created_at) %></th>
      <th><%=t '.actions', :default => t("helpers.actions") %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @servers.each do |server| %>
      <tr>
  <!--      <td><%= link_to server.id, server_path(server) %></td> -->
        <td><%= server.hostname %></td>
        <td><%= server.port %></td>
   <!--     <td><%= server.username %></td>
        <td><%= server.password %></td>
        <td><%= server.ssh_username %></td>
        <td><%= server.ssh_password %></td>
        <td><%= server.source_branch %></td> -->
        <td><%= server.source_revision %></td>
        <td><%= server.release %></td>
        <td id="comments"><%= server.rhel_version %></td>
        <td><%= server.gpu_type %></td>
        <td><%= server.total_users %></td>
        <td><%= server.current_users %></td>
        <td><%=l server.created_at %></td>
        <td>
          <%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
                      edit_server_path(server), :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
          <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
                      server_path(server),
                      :method => :delete,
                      :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')),
                      :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= link_to t('.new', :default => t("helpers.links.new")),
            new_server_path,
            :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

**application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Does the javascript run if you remove the second line? Try just running the alert by itself.

Comment: removing the second line still does not work :(

Comment: And you're sure that the index action is even getting called?

Comment: Thats what I am thinking, format.js isnt calling index.js.erb but I am unsure how to go about solving this.

Comment: Move the call to `format.js` above the `format.html` in your controller

Comment: Can you post you log file entry when index action is invoked?
Also can you post the code from where you're invoking this controller action?

Comment: have you found solution to this problem, I am facing exactly same problem ?

Comment: As am I, I have tried Rails 6 on multiple machines, Linux, Heroku it's like js.erb files  just globally all stopped working?!?

Answer (score 2):

Point your browser to `/servers.js`  and it will show the js, but won't run as it's not in a script tag.

The `respond_to` section chooses one and only one media type to respond to, so when you are looking at a html page, if you want some javascript included, it needs to be in the html page in a script tag somehow.  The index.js.erb format is for requests that are made solely for javascript output, such as ajax requests.

Comment: So have a method.js file for def method works with also including ruby code <% %> in rails 4? before you where required to add .erb in the extension

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, though here is the solution, because I stumbled over this problem twice this day, without even remembering ;)

According to [**this**](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-js-erb-remote-response-not-executing/) blog post, you should check your `request type`. It has to be `JS`. If you're requesting that controller action via `AJAX`, just leave out the `dataType-attribute`. This will set the request type as `*/*`, but it will still work.

**Example:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/users/auth/facebook/callback',
    type: 'GET'
});
```

**EDIT**

The request to the controller should look like this:

```
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as JS
```

With my solution it will look like this:

```
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as */*
```

Setting the dataType to 'JS' didn't work for me, but it will still work as if it were a JS.